# How to restart OpenVPN Access Server via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using the "OpenVPN Access Server" AMI EC2 instance from AWS.

According to https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?p=12848#p12848 `/etc/init.d/openvpn restart` should restart OpenVPN server on Debian (I'm running Ubuntu, which is Debian) but when I try that I get this:

```
bash: /etc/init.d/openvpn: No such file or directory
```

When I do `service openvpn restart` (which should work on CentOS per the above post) I get this:

```
Failed to restart openvpn.service: Unit openvpn.service not found.
```

I did `locate openvpn` but got 3,860 entries back per `locate openvpn | wc -l`...

If it helps, here's the banner that I see when I login:

```
Welcome to OpenVPN Access Server Appliance 2.7.5

  System information as of Tue Oct 12 06:00:15 UTC 2021

  System load:  0.0               Users logged in:      0
  Usage of /:   75.6% of 7.69GB   IP address for eth0:  172.31.7.187
  Memory usage: 42%               IP address for as0t0: 172.27.224.1
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for as0t1: 172.27.232.1
  Processes:    103

Last login: Tue Oct 12 04:04:04 2021 from 70.124.147.35
```

So how do I restart OpenVPN Access Server?

I guess I could just reboot the server but is there a way to restart OpenVPN Access Server without rebooting the entire machine?

Comment: Again, you have to refer to docs of that Access Server. The `service openvpn restart` or `service openvpn@something restart` (if you have several VPNs) is valid for Community edition which is what we're familiar with, I dobut many of us know what they did with that in Access Server. Just remember: **OpenVPN Access Server ≠ OpenVPN** (by the way, `openvpn` tag is not valid, because it explicitely for open source version and doesn't fit Access Server). NB: tried to see a list of all services with something like `systemctl list-units --type=service`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service openvpnas restart` does the trick